# Why my IF condition is not taken correctly

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Good afternoon Dev community,
I'm working on a PHP project.
My first page is a formular that ask something like : What are you doing now?
This info POST in an other page call "Handler.php"

I would like to set a variable ($hnormale) regarding what user answers just before.
To do that I use a IF function but it doesn't works.

Here formular's code:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:100px"><h4>Nom:</h4></td>
    <td>
        <SELECT NAME=nom >
           <OPTION value=users1>user1</OPTION>
           <OPTION value=user2>user2</OPTION>
           <OPTION value=user3>Sonia</OPTION>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td><h4>Activit&#233;:</h4></td>
    <td>
        <SELECT NAME=activite  style="width:182px">
          <OPTION value="arrived">arrived</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="gotolunch">gotolunch</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="backfromlunch">backfromlunch</OPTION>      
          <OPTION value="leave">leave</OPTION>      
    </td>
</tr></td></tr>
<tr><td><h4>Commentaires:</h4></td><td><input type="text" name="commentaires" style="width:182px" /></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an extract of handler.php page :

```
    $hnormale = "09:00";
    $activite = $_POST["activite"];

    if ($activite == "backfromlunch") 
    {
       $hnormale = "14:00";
       echo $hnormale;
    }
    else 
    { 
       echo "it doesn't works";
    }
```

Comment: You have a lot of missing quotes. One of which being for `<SELECT NAME=nom >` more importantly for `<SELECT NAME=activite` - Plus, you also need to place your form tags outside your table tags.

Comment: You have not closed either of your `<SELECT>` tags.

Comment: Your code is working here: http://sugunan.net/demo/form3.php without any change. But better to fix all those HTML issues as above comments. You can validate your HTML at following website: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes, like this

```
<SELECT NAME="activite"  style="width:182px">

<SELECT NAME="nom" >
```

and close the SELECT tags

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would change your if statement to a switch (it isnt why it's not working but it is cleaner):

```
<?php
switch ($activite) {
    case "arrived":
        $hnormale = "Working";
        echo $hnormale;
        break;
    case "gotolunch":
        $hnormale = "Working";
        echo $hnormale;
        break;
    case "backfromlunch":
        $hnormale = "Working";
        echo $hnormale;
        break;
    case "leave":
        $hnormale = "Working";
        echo $hnormale;
        break;
    default:   //This is for if the case does not match any of the above.
        echo "It doesn't work.";
        break;
}
?>
```

But you are missing lots of quotes for example your values on the first select and you didn't close the SELECT.

Comment: Thank for your help.sorryfor " issue. I translated it quick and I lost some caracteres. I'd tested what you proposed me (Add " and with Switch) and nothing works. The switch solution always return "It doesn't works" to IF condition is never applyed. Any others idea or test to do? Thx for your help

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add semicolons after the echos. Here is a working version: http://codepad.viper-7.com/c2pJCX